# #if DEBUG doesn't seem to work

Tags: c#

My C# app is in debug mode. I am trying to use Debug.WriteLine(xxx) but nothing is written to the Console. I'm using VS 2013 Community with C#. I have #define DEBUG at the start of the cs file, above the using statements and then #IF DEBUG before the Debug.WriteLine() statements but nothing happens. No errors.

Comment: Can you show the code where you are trying to use it?

Comment: `Debug.WriteLine` *doesn't* write to the console, it writes to trace listeners.

Comment: You might want to look into how to implament [#IF DEBUG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The debug output isn't redirected to the console by default.

You can create a `ConsoleTraceListener` instance and add to the trace listeners, that will make the debug output go to the console:

```
using (ConsoleTraceListener listener = new ConsoleTraceListener()) {
  Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);

  Debug.WriteLine("test");

}
```

You can also do that in the configuration, so that it applies to the application without adding code. Example:

```
<configuration>
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="false" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="configConsoleListener"
             type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
 </configuration>
```

Reference: [ConsoleTraceListener Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.consoletracelistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the Output console of the Visual Studio? If you're running your app in Visual studio (=debugging), Debug output is forwarded there.

Comment: If you mean the same output that Console uses? I use that.